# Excel 2013 How can I reference data across multiple worksheets + Randomize Table content?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to create a complex spreadsheet in my opinion because I am not advanced skilled in excel and that is why I am here.I will also provide pictures for better understanding.

Here is my scenario:
I belong to a fishing club and we have a massive competition on the way and the guys asked me to draw up a spreadsheet to help out with the competition winners.

With that being said I have created multiple sheets to help somewhat with the process. Each link is a spreadsheet name and its containing data.

---

This sheet  is where we are going to enter our teams in this case there are only 2 for examples but will add about 100 Teams.
[image: Step1]

---

This sheet is where the competition actually takes place and the winners will be calculated on which leads me to the next spreadsheet...

[image: Step2]

Rankings: This is where the winners of each sector contained by "Step2" will be displayed. (Unfortunately I can't post more than 2 links at this stage)

Team Rankings: This is where the team rankings will be displayed.

Now that we can use these pictures as reference the scenario begins:
I have created Step1 because that is where all the teams and their members will be entered before we can proceed to step2. Teams consist of only 4 people and there will be only 4 sectors called Sector A - D. There will however be sub sectors labeled Sector A1 - 4 and same with B, C and D.

1.) Is it possible to Randomize where the members will be divided into Step2 because there can only be one member of a team in each sector?

2.) Can the members plus the team name be pulled from Step1 to Step2 without copy and Paste function and in the correct "Randomized" column?

That will be basically all for now because the rest of what needs to be done I can do.

Comment: So each team needs a member in A, B, C, and D. Or they need to have members *not* in the same *sub*-category, so they could be A1, A4, C3, D2? Do all sectors and sub-sectors need to have the same number of competitors?

Comment: Yes each member needs to be in a different Sector so there can only be one member in all of Sector A and one in B, C and D. There can be a max of 10 teams in each Sector before they need to go down to Sector A2, B2, C2 and D2. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so if the member names are put in random order when entered, every first person could be A, second B, etc? And then the first 10 A's would be A1, the next 10 As would be A2, etc? That way you only need to randomize the team names to the sectors?

Comment: Yes that is correct, then the First 10 B's will be in B1 and the next ten B's will be in B2 etc. So the more teams enter the more the sectors will fill up.

So if there are 40 teams they will be divided equally of 10 teams per sector A, B, C, D. There mus be an equal division for the competition to be fair.

Comment: So can this be done on the Step1 sheet or should it be done on a whole new sheet?

Comment: Let me try again. A good idea might be to take a list of the team and assign them a random number. That number is where they land for each letter. You could do that for each letter. Then you only need a `vlookup` to take the team name and find the member that's using that letter. So like 11 would be A2.

Comment: A different sheet, then use the vlookup based on the table you created and the team tables to populate the sectors. I mean it could be done on the team listing sheet, but that might look messy.

Comment: You could do this by putting the names in a list and just using `rand()` and then copy the values and rank them, or put them in order, or whatever. You shouldn't get any duplicates.

Comment: Okey cool thanks and then do I use Vlookup in each block in Spreadsheet Step2 or how do I draw the required information from Step1 to Step2 in their respective fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is once you gets all the team names, create a list of them like -

- sharks
- jets
- thunderbirds
- breadsticks

Then next to them use `=Rand()`. Then copy and paste special - values over top the rand() so it doesn't change. Then you can use `Rank()` or just filter small to large on that list.

For the first 10 just use a hlookup to find the team and the member.

So if the list says -

```
 sharks        1004
 jets          23
 thunderbirds  10478
 breadsticks   5006
```

Then sector A1 would be `=hlookup(JETS, JETS TABLE,1,0)` to get the first person in jets. next cell in A1 would be `hlookup(SHARKS, SHARKS TABLE, 1 0)` and so on.

After the first 10, move to sector A2 and do it for the next 10 teams and so on.

Then do another `rand()` on teams for the B sectors. etc.

---

If that doesn't work, then you could just move the team names and first member to a list and `rand()` those. Then the teams with their second member, and so on.

Either way you would have a list of say 30 teams in order with 1-10 in A1, 11-20 in A2, 21-30 in A3. Then the same thing but different order for B, C, D..

---

You could also use a vlookup by transfering the rand() to the team spreadsheet in column A and then using the same rand numbers to populate the sectors.

I would mock some screenshots up, but I just hate using excel on OSX.